# Is the 'else if' redundant in this function?

Tags: c, if-statement, return, control-flow

So, with the following function in a C program to determine whether a number is prime or composite:

```
/** 
 * Determine if a given integer is prime. O(sqrt n).
 * n: The integer to examine.
 * return: TRUE if n is prime; FALSE if n is not prime.
 */
BOOL APIENTRY IsPrime(int n)
{
    int i;
    double test;
    if(n <= 1) return FALSE;
    else if(n <= 3) return TRUE; // Is the else keyword at beginning of this line useful?

    for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        test = (double) n / (double) i;
        if (test == floor(test)) return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

If I replaced line 12 with just `if (n <= 3) return TRUE;` the function would still work properly (since the previous `if` statement catches the cases where n is not prime on the premise that it is 1, 0 or negative).  Should I leave the `else` keyword present regardless?

Comment: I believe it's a matter of style in this case.

Comment: Using floating point arithmetic to do integer calculations is likely to lead to trouble eventually.

Comment: Remember that there are two audiences for source code: the compiler, and the maintainers. As you point out, the compiler will hopefully recognize the `return` and make the `else` redundant. But what about the maintainers? If the `else` adds value - by communicating to them that this is an exclusive case - then keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation it's irrelevant since you are returning from the code. In both cases the compiled code will jump to `if (n <= 3)` when `n > 1`, no matter what.

This because the second condition must be always evaluated if first `if` statement is false. This can be easily seen (and should be always verified directly) in the assembler output of both functions:

```
Ltmp7:
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    jge LBB0_2
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp LBB0_8 // jump to return false
LBB0_2:
    movb    $1, %r14b
    cmpl    $4, %edi
    jl  LBB0_3 // jump to return true
```

vs

```
Ltmp15:
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    jge LBB1_2
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp LBB1_8 // jump to return false
LBB1_2:
    movb    $1, %r14b
    cmpl    $4, %edi
    jl  LBB1_3 // jump to return true
```

An interesting twist is given by modifying the code to something like

```
if (n <= 3) return n > 1;
```

because now you have just a branch so it could be optimized differently, for example on my compiler (clang-3.4) it yields

```
cmpl    $4, %edi
jge LBB0_1 // jump to function body
cmpl    $1, %edi
setg    %al
jmp LBB0_7 // jump to return with $al register already set
```

which uses the `setg` instruction to directly set the return value according to the previous comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(n <= 1) return FALSE;
else if(n <= 3) return TRUE;
```

and

```
if(n <= 1) return FALSE;
if(n <= 3) return TRUE;
```

are the same because `return FALSE;` ends the execution of current function (as any `return` statement). So the assembly code generated should be the same, you can keep it or not as whatever seems more readable to you.

Comment: `return` ends execution, no matter `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler is smart enough, the compiled code will be the same with or without the `else` before the `if`.

But, in your code, you wrote:

```
for (...; n<= sqrt(n); ...)
```

Which could (it depends again on the compiler) call the `sqrt` function at each loop iteration.

Replace with :

```
int limit = sqrt(n);
for (i = 3; i <= limit; i +=2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an `else` after an `if` branch returning unconditionally is always redundant:

```
if (someCondition) {
    ... do something, then
    return someValue;
} // <<== An "else" here would be redundant
... more code
```

The only way to reach the "more code" line is for `someCondition` to evaluate to `false`, which is identical to the condition of reaching the `else` branch.

The same is true about `if` branches with other kinds of unconditional transfer of control, such as `break` and `continue`. Code analysis tools exist to warn programmers of the redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you, *really*.

Moreover, `i` starts from 2, so yes, you can discard it.

---

Off-topic: Why you use floating-point arithmetic? You want to find prime numbers. You may face problems with that, beware!

Comment: I'm using floating point arithmetic because I couldn't think of a better way to test for finding a factor of n than doing a division and testing the floor() of the result.

Comment: @GovindParmar, take an idea from my code here: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/isprime-c/